# no response from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm going nuts with this issue and have no idea what is wrong.
What i'm trying to do is a simple AJAX call to get URLs of images and thumbnails for current menu from database.
I have a function inside my object literal like this:

```
infoBlink: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'menu_id' : $(".activeMenu").attr('id')
            },
            error: function(xhr, error){
                console.log(xhr); 
                console.log(error);
            },
            sucess: function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
        console.log("menu_id: " + $(".activeMenu").attr('id'));
    },
```

It references a php file with the following code:

```
require_once('fns/classes/graphics.php');

if(isset($_POST['menu_id']) && !empty($_POST['menu_id'])) {
        $menu_id = $_POST['menu_id'];
        $gfx = new Graphics();
        $result = $gfx->getForId($menu_id);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

which then uses a function from Graphics class residing in another file:

```
public function getForId($menu_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("select * from graphics where menu_id=? ");
    $query->bindParam(1, $menu_id);
    if ($query->execute()) {
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, I've tested the ajax.php on it's own and it returns all the needed data from database perfectly, for example:

```
[{"id":"4","menu_id":"2","name":"logo_v2_vert.jpg","url":"images\/logo_v2_vert.jpg","thumbnail_url":"images\/thumbnails\/logo_v2.jpg"}]
```

, but when I use AJAX absolutely nothing happens. Neither the error nor the success callback gets executed, just nothing at all.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using firebug or developer console? What does it have to say?

Comment: I'm using Chrome's console, the thing is it doesn't say anything. It logs anything that i put on the event handler which fires the functions (which was click for testing purpose), but nothing from the ajax itself.

Comment: I hope this isn't the issue, but `success` is spelled wrong in your AJAX call.

Comment: the misspelled success is the only possible way for neither error nor success to happen without causing a syntax or request error

Comment: @KevinB -- Will it show the request being sent at all?

Comment: How could I miss that... Indeed, that was the issue. Thanks for the quick notice!

Comment: @RichardA: Problems/questions due to typos should be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick typo caused all of this. You have `success` spelled wrong in your AJAX call. Change:

```
sucess: function(data){
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
},
```

To:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
},
```